# How to sink structured records directly from KSQL into a connector (e.g., InfluxDB)

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I'm trying to sink data directly from KSQL into InfluxDB (or any other connector that would require definitions). I'm able to get things working in the simple case, but I start having trouble when the schema requires complex types. (I.e., tags for InfuxDB).

Here's an example of my stream/schema:

```
 Field    | Type                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 ROWKEY   | VARCHAR(STRING)  (primary key)
 FIELD_1  | VARCHAR(STRING)                                        
 FIELD_2  | VARCHAR(STRING)                                        
 FIELD_3  | VARCHAR(STRING)                                        
 FIELD_4  | DOUBLE                                                 
 TAGS     | MAP<STRING, VARCHAR(STRING)>
```

If I manually create an AVRO schema and populate the records from a simple producer, I can get through the getting started guide [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-influxdb/influx-db-sink-connector/index.html#avro-tags-example) and embed the tags for InfluxDB.

However, when I move to KSQL, if I try to sink the AVRO stream *directly* into InfluxDB, I lose information on the complex types (tags). I notice the warning from this [blog post](https://rmoff.net/2020/01/23/notes-on-getting-data-into-influxdb-from-kafka-with-kafka-connect/), "Warning ksqlDB/KSQL cannot yet write data in an Avro format that is compatible with this connector"

Next, I try converting the AVRO stream into JSON format, but now I understand that I would have to specify the schema in each record, similar to what this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991499/attaching-json-schema-to-ksql-stream-records) is posing. I haven't been able to convert an AVRO stream into a JSON stream and embed the schema and payload at the same time.

Finally, I see the ["jiggling solution"](https://rmoff.net/2020/01/21/monitoring-sonos-with-ksqldb-influxdb-and-grafana/) with kafkacat, but this would force me to dump records out from KSQL into kafkacat, and then back into Kafka before finally arriving at Influx.

Is there a method to sink complex records directly from KSQL in either JSON or AVRO format into a connector?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the reason ksqlDB can't yet output the AVRO data in the format InfluxDB requires is because it won't output the `TAGS` field as an Avro `map` type due to Avro maps requiring a non-null key and the SQL `MAP<STRING, STRING>` type allowing null keys.  Hence ksqlDB serializes the map as an Avro `array` of key-value entries.

To get something working with Avro you'll need either:

1. Support for non-null types: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4436, or
2. Support for using existing Avro schema: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3634

Please feel free to up-vote / comment on these issues to raise their profiles.

Previously, a JSON based solution would not of worked because, as you've pointed out, the connector requires the JSON schema embedded in the payload. However, the most recent version of Confluent Platform / Schema Registry supports JSON schemas in the Schema Registry.  Hence, while I haven't tried it, upgrading to the latest CP version may mean a JSON based solution will work. If not, it is probably work raise a Jira/Github ticket to get the appropriate component upgraded for this to work.